# SPServices: How would I add Ascending=False to CAML in GetListItems

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, caml-query, spservices

How would I use SPServices GetListItems and still be able to add Ascending=False to the CAMLViewFields? I haven't used this for long and I am just wondering if this is possible?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the `Ascending=False` as an attribute of the `FieldRef` in the `OrderBy` element.

```
 $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "EmployeeList",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeID'/><Value Type='Text'>1</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>",
    CAMLRowLimit: 1,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

var idquery=""; 
$().SPServices({
 operation: "GetListItems", 
async: false, 
listName: "test", 
CAMLQuery: idquery, 
CAMLRowLimit: 1, 
completefunc: function (xData, Status) 
{ 
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { //alert($(this).attr("ows_Title")); 
var getvalue= parseInt($(this).attr("ows_Title"))+1;//Auto increment value $("input[title='TicketNumber']").val(getvalue);

        });
     } 
    });
```

[Full details](http://peakfinders.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-get-id-of-last-inserted-row-in.html)

Comment: Just code will not help future readers. Please add some content of description from the link you have provided.